# Grails domain constraints definition

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Grails application with a -simplified - domain class which looks like this:

```
class Capacity {

static constraints = {              
    month(blank:false, nullable:false)
    company(blank:false, nullable:false)
}


Date month    
Company company
String note
...
}
```

The pair **month-company** must be unique. (I.e. they should be primary key at the DB).

How can I define such a constraint?

Thanks a lot in advance

Luis

Comment: it's just Grails, not Groovy on Grails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want this to be a [composite primary key](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2.5%20Composite%20Primary%20Keys) in the DB you will have to declare that mapping:

```
class Capacity implements Serializable {
    Date month    
    Company company
    String note
    ...

    static mapping = { 
        id composite:['month', 'company'] 
    } 
}
```

Which Produces the following table(MySQL):

```
CREATE
    TABLE capacity
    (
        MONTH DATETIME NOT NULL,
        company_id bigint NOT NULL,
        version bigint NOT NULL,
        note VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (MONTH, company_id),
        INDEX FKFBF514BA69595C7A (company_id)
    )
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Does this still enforce the uniqueness during `validate()`? If not, I think a combination of this answer and Dave's are needed. Otherwise you'll end up getting SQL constraint exceptions instead of Grails validation errors.

Comment: @RobHruska Some of the constraints use the state of the database to validate and aren't there in unit testing (before Grails 2.0)

Answer (score 5):

It should be something like:

```
static constraints = {              
    month(blank:false, nullable:false, unique:'company')
    company(blank:false, nullable:false)
}
```

Take a look at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html.